# lenovo x1 yoga freeze

Tags: lenovo, freeze

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo X1 Yoga. I experience system crashes. The screen freezes and all the keys become unresponsive. The kernel version is 
4.9.20-040920-generic

What should I do?

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. I can try to boot with a supported version and see if the problem is still there. Which one is the latest supported kernel version?

Comment: @Fabby [yes they are](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5576/85695). [Always have been](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/6190/85695). Please don't follow Pilot in his choice to ignore our scope and precedent.

Comment: @Pilot I have already asked you this once before. If you want to change the site's scope, take it to meta and make your case. Until you do, stop spreading wrong information about what is and is not on topic. You don't get to single-handedly decide the site's scope.

Comment: @VincenzoAlba custom kernels do not make your question off topic. I'm sorry you were misled.